# How to get Type.length

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get type's length, but just use variable like this : `const testTypeLength = 4;`

I wonder is it possible in typescript:

```
  type Test = "T" | "e" | "s" | "t";
  console.log(Test.length)
```

Comment: I wonder what the practical application of this would be. I don't think you'd really want to use amount of members in a type for any sort of production code, although I see some value of this as statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types are only present at compile type and erased during compilation. So no javascript value can be created based on a type (one of the guiding principles in TS is that the compiler should not do any type directed emit, it just checks that the types are valid and erases the types)

You can however go the other way around, from a value to a type. So you can start with an array and get the `Test` type. And having the array you can get the `length` or whatever other value you need:

```
const Test = ["T", "e", "s", "t"] as const
type Test = typeof Test[number]; // same as before ( type Test = "T" | "e" | "s" | "t") but extracted from the const
console.log(Test.length) // ok accesing the const Test
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgU2jAvDA2gIjpgNDTBPAiYzKTAXRgEMIZRIoBYAKCgE8AHBeJWNJx4gAZn2jowAVwC2AIwQAnSgG4YAenUwINGbzowFIkIt4AKGEN6JkabJhgAfAkSckHz8pgCUhqbAQADyhFGmAoBAATGBFFEBlLAAteRmg2VJAAGwQAOkyQAHMzGyg8hDACqETfTRgQAGtaYGAkAEsKpJTwZBKgA)